# Mocking HttpResponse Angular2 in a unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking

In one of the unit tests I need to mock a http response, I think I was doing that by the book but it seems that for whatever reason I am getting the following exception:

```
‘TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined’
```

This is in reference to this line:

```
 mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection)


describe('ServiceUnderTest', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ServiceUnderTest, MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions,
        { provide: XHRBackend, useExisting: MockBackend },
        {
          provide: Http,
          deps: [XHRBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
          useFactory: (backend, options) => { return new Http(backend, options); },
        }],
      imports: [HttpModule],
    });
  });

 it('should return array', async(inject([ServiceUnderTest, MockBackend], (service: ServiceUnderTest, mockBackend) => {

    const mockResponse: any = {
      data: [
        { 'code': '123', 'desc': 'ab' },
        { 'code': '345', 'desc': 'cd' },         
      ],
    };

    // Line which throws error
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
        body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse),
      })));
    });

    service.getMyGear().subscribe(result => {
      let fishingGears: Array<any> = result;
      expect(fishingGears.length).toBe(3);
      expect(fishingGears[0].desc).toBe('Pots');
    });
```

The following workaround fixes the problem:

```
mockBackend.http._backend.connections
```

As per the documentation property: mockBackend.connections should only exist in the mock implementation.

Any ideas why this property doesn't exist?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue with what I have been passing to the test - it was actually an empty object!